# Using object-fit: cover for specific grid items

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a basic image grid layout, where most grid items are their natural size, but two others are a subdivided size and cropped. Here's an example image of what 'd like to achieve:

[image]

The red images should determine the size of the red grid units. The blue images should occupy half the height of the red images and be cropped accordingly.

I'm working with the following code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.grid img:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.grid img:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.grid img:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}
.grid img:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.grid img:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
        <img src="https://ericcarl.link/images/amtrea-blind-contour.jpg">
        <img src="https://ericcarl.link/images/amtrea-blind-contour.jpg">
        <img src="https://ericcarl.link/images/amtrea-blind-contour.jpg">
        <img src="https://ericcarl.link/images/eca-scent-cover.jpg">
        <img src="https://ericcarl.link/images/eca-scent-cover.jpg">
</div>
```

Codepen example here: https://codepen.io/ericcarl/pen/PoaooQY.

I'm trying to use object-fit: cover on the last two images but they aren't getting cropped. Instead they are displayed full height, I assume because there's nothing here telling them they should be any shorter. How might I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your grid like below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.grid img:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.grid img:nth-child(4),
.grid img:nth-child(5) {
  /* this will force the image to follow the left one */
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 0;
  /**/
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://ericcarl.link/images/amtrea-blind-contour.jpg">
  <img src="https://ericcarl.link/images/amtrea-blind-contour.jpg">
  <img src="https://ericcarl.link/images/amtrea-blind-contour.jpg">
  <img src="https://ericcarl.link/images/eca-scent-cover.jpg">
  <img src="https://ericcarl.link/images/eca-scent-cover.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! It works in Chrome, however I don't see the two smaller images in Safari. Is something else needed for Safari?